# Insert custom Object from Lightning component (JSON)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, json

I have created a component which takes users input and when the submit button is hit I want the component to insert my transaction__c records from the created JSONList,

As it stands my example json looks like so for 2 transaction records:

> {"sobjectType":"Transaction__c","Contract__c":"8004E000000DMwqQAG","Related_Asset__c":"02i4E0000009hBdQAI","Billable_Month__c":"2017-11-06","Number_of_Transactions__c":"10000"},{"sobjectType":"Transaction__c","Contract__c":"8004E000000DUehQAG","Related_Asset__c":"02i4E000000A2ARQA0","Billable_Month__c":"2017-11-06","Number_of_Transactions__c":"500"}

This list is past into the apex controller "insertTransactions" method which I currently have like so:

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static void insertTransactions(String tListJSON) {
        try{
        //insert tListJSON;
        }
        catch(exception e){
            System.debug('error inserting transactions @ ' + e);
        }
    }
```

I have tried creating a json2apex class but the __c isn't accepted so what are my options here for getting this to insert correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [JSON class in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) to deserialize it:

```
JSON.deserialize(tListJSON, List<Transaction__c>.class);
```

Comment: Another option is to use a wrapper class as you would be 100% sure on what to expect with serialize/de-serialize